# Generate sequence of 1 11 111 1111 for every n iterations

Tags: python, logic

I am trying to achieve this

```
1*1 = 1
11*11 = 121
111 * 111 = 12321
```

for every n input given by the user. (n=3) in the case of this example.

This is what I have so far:

```
i_times = int(input('Enter number of times: '))
i = 1
values = []

while (i <= i_times):
    a = (([1] * i))
    b = (([1] * i))
    value = a * b
    values.append(values)

    i = +1

for a in values:
    print(a)
```

Any insights? as I get this error:

```
value = a * b
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are both lists of 1's. What result do you hope to get by trying to multiply two lists (which is not allowed)?

Comment: Instead of using lists, you can convert strings to integers like `int('1'*3)` ->  `111`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example of Producing

```
def times(n):
  " Produces ['1', '11', ...] "
  return ['1'*k for k in range(1, n+1)]

i_times = int(input('Enter number of times: '))

for x in times(i_times):
  print(f'{x} x {x} = {int(x)**2}')
```

**Output**

```
Enter number of times: 5
1 x 1 = 1
11 x 11 = 121
111 x 111 = 12321
1111 x 1111 = 1234321
11111 x 11111 = 123454321
```